# how to map point cloud Data comming from serial port

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a serial data frame, it contains some points defined at (X,Y,Z) and another information, i have received this frame in ROS, and extracted the data related to point cloud, now how can i visualize these points in RVIZ, and if i want to implement slam later what is the data type involved to encapsulate these points

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361562/how-to-map-point-cloud-data-comming-from-serial-port/) by [MjdKassem](https://answers.ros.org/users/43130/mjdkassem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your best bet is to populate a `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` and publish it. A topic with this message type can natively be visualized in Rviz. If you're looking for an example of populating this type of message, check out any of the lidar drivers such as the [Velodyne driver for melodic](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/tree/melodic-devel).

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MjdKassem](https://answers.ros.org/users/43130/mjdkassem/) on 2020-09-19**:
thank you, what is the purpose of converting from `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` to PCL datatypes

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-09-19**:
Purely for convenience of editing the data. PCL is not a requirement (see the [ros2 version](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/tree/ros2) for an example without PCL).